# How to set custom notification sound for Desktop (Chrome/Firefox) web push app using FCM?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, push-notification, web-push

I want to send Notification with custom sound In web App (Desktop Chrome Or Mozilla) Is it possible to send custom sound, I tried alot not finding any relevent solutions..

Comment: any update for this? i also need a sound effect for web push notification when it's in background